# How to press "TAB" then "ENTER" key in Selenium WebDriver using Java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, tabs

I am doing automation testing using java with Selenium WebDriver. I want to click on tabs. I would like to check tab functionality.

I can use Tab key to get the button as below:

```
WebElement webElement = driver.findElementByXPath("");
webElement.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
webElement.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

I have a form with multiple fields I want to track upon pressing key tab key is my control moving to next field successfully or not. Also I want to check upon which my control is below is my form [image]

But how do I click one by one tab.
Basically I need to achieve press Tab key and then press Enter key to click the button.

I learning selenium.
Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: First you should click inside the box, then send TAB, then ESCAPE (remember, that "ENTER" is not the "enter" on the keyboard, the right one is "ESCAPE").

Comment: Could you please provide this form link or html?

Answer (score 3):

Please see the solution that works with my example form

FormTab.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form>
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
    <br>
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<p>If you click "Submit", nothing happens.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Java code:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

//Insert path to your file
driver.get("FormTab.html");

//Three example elements
WebElement firstField = driver.findElement(By.name("firstname"));
WebElement secondField = driver.findElement(By.name("lastname"));
WebElement submit = driver.findElement(By.name("submit"));

//Start with the first field
firstField.sendKeys();
//Verify that we in the first field
if(driver.switchTo().activeElement().equals(firstField))
    System.out.println("First element is in a focus");
else
    //Add Assertion here - stop execution
    System.out.println("ASSERTION - first element not in the focus");

firstField.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);

//Verify that we in the second field
if(driver.switchTo().activeElement().equals(secondField))
    System.out.println("Second element is in a focus");
else
    //Add Assertion here - stop execution
    System.out.println("ASSERTION - second element not in the focus");

secondField.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);

if(driver.switchTo().activeElement().equals(submit))
    System.out.println("Submit element is in a focus");
else
    //Add Assertion here - stop execution
    System.out.println("ASSERTION - submit element not in the focus");

//Click the button 
submit.click();

//Need be closed also in case the assertion - use @After
driver.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code.This is working fine.

```
        Actions builder = new Actions(driver);         
        builder.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Tab).Build().Perform();
        builder.Release().Perform();            
        builder.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Tab).Build().Perform();
        builder.Release().Perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
        Action enter= builder
                .keyDown(Keys.TAB)
                .build();
enter.perform();

 Action releaseEnter= builder
                .keyUp(Keys.ENTER)
                .build();
releaseEnter.perform();
```

Comment: Your code seems to be press only Enter, but no code for pressing Tab

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use robot class of java to simulate pressing tabs and enters ot any other buttons , as much as you want, when you are on the page.